# Spotfire Python data function, how to reduce the table loading time?

Tags: python, spotfire

Here is the example code in my Python data function:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import pandas as pd
import io
import sys

pd_temp=pdtable
str1="Hello"
```

`pdtable` is input parameter.

`str1` is output parameter.

When the size of the input table is over 500,000 rows, the loading time of the table is very slow. It needs about 7 minutes. Is there a way to reduce the loading time?

Can the data function read sbdf files in the library?

addthe screenshot below
[image]

Comment: it's a input table, i added the screenshot.